# Counting consecutive 1's and 0's, up a certain value then reset counting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column 'threshold' from a df 'month' that looks like this:

```
threshold   
1
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I was using the following code to count across consecutive sequences of '1's:

```
thresh = np.asarray(month['threshold'].groupby(month['threshold'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumsum())
```

which achieved the following:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

I need to count sequences of exactly 5 (5 days is what it's standing for). Is there any way to get the code to count up to 5, then restart counting after it hits that 5? For example, what I wish the above array looked like:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

So no numbers greater than 5. Counting up to 5 and then restarting (at 1 if still a 1, otherwise it is a 0). After that I will be counting these instances of 5's, so in the above that would be 4 separate instances.

Comment: What would the output look like for this sample set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your base code:

```
>>> np.where(thresh > 5, (thresh - 1) % 5 + 1, thresh)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: This is not right.
At value 11 it will return a value of 6.

Comment: @AlbertoMQ. You are totally right! I fixed my answer. TY!

Comment: @spokati. I updated my answer after the comment of AlbertoMQ but the method is still the same.

Comment: Thank you for updating, I noticed this as I was playing around with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the `cumcount` with `%` with number `thresh = 5`

```
out = (month['threshold'].
       groupby(month['threshold'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).
       cumcount()%thresh +1).\
                   mask(month['threshold']==0,0)
Out[248]: 
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     0
6     1
7     2
8     3
9     4
10    5
11    1
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
20    0
21    1
22    2
23    3
24    4
25    5
26    1
27    2
28    3
29    4
30    5
dtype: int64
```